# Sorting objects in an array by field value as a parameter

Tags: javascript, sorting

This question is close to this one: [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript)

However, the field value should be chosen by the user (saved in the `sortBy` parameter):

```
function sortList (sortBy, list) {
  return list.sort(function (val1, val2) {
    if (val1.sortBy > val2.sortBy) {

    return -1;
  }
  if (val1.sortBy < val2.sortBy) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;

  });
}

var myObj = [
  {a: 1, b: 3},
  {a: 3, b: 2},
  {a: 2, b: 40},
  {a: 4, b: 12}
];

sortList(myObj.a, myObj);
```

The object returns unchanged.

Comment: The second answer to the linked question shows how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4760279/218196

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close:

```
function sortList (sortBy, list) {
  return list.sort(function (val1, val2) {
    if (val1[sortBy] > val2[sortBy]) {

    return -1;
  }
  if (val1[sortBy] < val2[sortBy]) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;

  });
}

var myObj = [
  {a: 1, b: 3},
  {a: 3, b: 2},
  {a: 2, b: 40},
  {a: 4, b: 12}
];

sortList("a", myObj);
```

If you want to access properties by some computed value, you use the `[ ]` operator instead of `.`. As it was, your code was always only looking for a property called "sortBy", and the passed-in parameter was ignored.